# VB6 com interoperability - single class

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I have a class library that contains a bunch of classes (say 20). I want to expose one of those classes as a type library to a vb6 client..

Do I have to put the single class in a separate class library or is there a way to expose a single class? I have read a few examples, which assume that every class in the class library is com visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IDE gives a quick way to make all *Public* classes visible in a type library.  But that's not the only option, you can also apply the `<ComVisible(true)>` attribute in your code on each individual class and interface.